# Python dict MultiSet

Tags: python, dictionary, multiset

How do I write the code in Python by using dict?

The MultiSet ADT:

**init**(self) -

add(item, m) - Add item to the multiset with multiplicity m . If no multiplicity is given, it should default to multiplicity = 1.

remove(item, m) - Remove m copies of item from the multiset. If fewer than m copies are in the multiset, it should just remove all of them.

mult(item) - return the multiplicity of item in the multiset. If
item is not in the multiset, then return 0 .

contains(item, m) - Return True if item appears in the multiset with multiplicity at least m . Return False otherwise.

Comment: Hi! Looking at your last few questions, they seem to be not actual questions but specifications, and you're hoping for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Seems like you just need to create a wrapper around `collections.Counter` or even a dict with an int counter as its value elements, if you are not allowed to use Counter.

Comment: Have a look at the Counter class in collections, which is a standard part of the Python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Counter from collections, and just record the frequency each unique element appears. No need not invent another wheel.